# Как сделать разброс пуль в Unity 2D?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нужен разброс пуль в Top down shooter. Снизу код который сейчас. Как я думаю, нужно просто добавить градус к уже готовому градусу пули, но как? На видео показал как выглядит стрельба сейчас. переменная `Scatter` должна обозначать силу разброса, типо - градус пули + `Random.Range(-Scatter, Scatter);`

Видео - https://youtu.be/65QBea-_6u4

Мой вариант не работает/работает странно:

```
private void Shoot()
{
    Quaternion Angle = transform.parent.parent.rotation;
    Angle.z += Random.Range(-Scatter, Scatter);
    GameObject Bullet = Instantiate(BulletPrefab, ShootPos.position, Angle);
    Bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = transform.parent.parent.right * BulletForce * 
    Time.fixedDeltaTime;
}
```

Код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Pistol : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject BulletPrefab;
    public Transform ShootPos;
    public float BulletForce;
    public int Scatter;
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
        {
            Shoot();
        }
    }
    private void Shoot()
    {
        GameObject Bullet = Instantiate(BulletPrefab, ShootPos.position, Angle);
        Bullet.GetComponent().velocity = transform.parent.parent.right * BulletForce * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[DisallowMultipleComponent]

// логичней что спускает курок персонаж...
public class Player : MonoBehaviour () {

    [SerializeField] private Gun _gun;

    // почему FixedUpdate? как это связано с апдейтом физики?
    private void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0) && _gun != null)
            _gun.Shoot();
    }
}
```

---

```
[DisallowMultipleComponent]

public class Gun : MonoBehaviour {

    // тут нет полей которые должны быть public
    [SerializeField] private float _scatter;
    [Space]
    [SerializeField] private Transform _firePoint;
    [SerializeField] private Bullet _bulletTeplate;

    public void Shoot () {
        if (_bulletTeplate != null) {
            // привычный нам угол в градумах, это углы эйлера, а не Quaternion
            Vector3 Angle = _firePoint.eulerAngles;
            Angle.z += Random.Range(-_scatter, _scatter);
            Instantiate(_bulletTeplate.gameObject, _firePoint.position, Quaternion.Euler(Angle));
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
[DisallowMultipleComponent]
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D))]

public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField] private float _speed;

    private void Start () {
        Rigidbody2D Body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        // зачем ты умножаешь скорость на дельту времени?
        // .forward зависит от поворота firePoint и самой пули
        Body.velocity = transform.forward*_speed;
    }
}
```

Comment: Да, но к каждой пуле будет прикреплен скрипт, разве от этого не будет лагать?

Comment: Обязательно будет, но не из за скриптов, темболее таких.